# I was wondering if their is a way to return the number of NIC's installed in a machine and the amount of bandwidth alocated to each machine?

Tags: python, psutil, python-netifaces

Here is a link to the code I have written so far. Eventually we are going to implement the code on the server and create a database. I am trying to pull in the most pertinent information I can to make things easier for our system administrators. As soon as I get some network information in the code, I am going to build out a database and then hopefully implement everything. Oh, here is the link to my pastebin code https://pastebin.com/8t69WeXv

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include everything needed to reproduce your problem without links. That will make it most likely for someone to answer.